# Can I sell Items (non-Oddities) right away?

Tags: torment-tides-of-numenera

I got this book, I believe from a crate in the first town:

[image: Item book]

The description says "Item", not Oddity or Artifact, and it's in my regular backpack, not the Quest Item section. I recently researched Oddities and found that most can be sold freely, while a few have subtle uses.

My question is, **for an Item, how do I know if this can be sold without penalty, or if it has an application elsewhere?** It has also crossed my mind that maybe this is what a Quest Item looks like before you pick up the quest? Maybe I'm wrong about that.

I am pretty new to the *Numenera*-verse, so I apologize if I am misunderstanding something fundamental about items or quests.